# How to enable --threads:on only for files using it?

Tags: nim-lang, nimble-nim

In a project producing multiple binaries, where only some of them are importing
a library (in this case "threadpool") which requires `--threads:on` to be passed
to the compiler, what would the way to handle this?

In my nimble file I have something like

```
srcDir = "src"
binDir = "bin" 
namedBin = {
    "program ": "program", 
    "prog_threads": "program-threads", 
}.toTable()
```

and at the moment I have `--threads:on` in my `nim.cfg` file, which results
in all the binaries being compiled with threads support.
I realized this is not what I need as it creates problems downstream, and I
would need a way to compile program without threads an prog_threads with it.

I'm using a "Makefile" as workaround, but I would love to be able to build
the project with `nimble build`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use config file per module. Put `--threads:on` into `<module name>.nim.cfg`